# How can I do usb tethering with Mac Os X (using gingerbread Acer Liquid Metal & snow leopard)?

Tags: usb-tethering, macos

I would like to use my Android phone to let my hackintosh (10.6 snow leopad) surf the internet.
The standard way of selecting usb tethering on android and plugging the usb cable tested on windows and ubuntu doesn't work...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EasyTether](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mstream.easytether_beta&feature=search_result) i think would be your best option. The free version is full-figured, and paying for the full market version will get you `https://` sites. And the drivers for it are available on [their website](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/drivers.html) for download.

P.S. it's only $4.99 right now in the Amazon Appstore ;)

Comment: It's not free and shame on apple and/or android for not implementing an easy and free solution like in windows or linux but...
It works :)

Comment: My dad swears by EasyTether. And once you have it, you can download the desktop client for all the other platforms if ya want ;)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the Wifi-Hotspot option (available since Android 2.2 (?))?
With this app, your android phone will act as a hotspot and your mac should be able to connect to it.

Comment: As I wrote in the question I need an usb solution

Comment: You just wrote that the USB solution doesnt work...

Comment: Right: it doesn't work.
That's why I'm here to ask...
Because I want it to work :)

Question is: "How can I do usb tethering with Mac Os X (using gingerbread Acer Liquid Metal & snow leopard)?"