# How to enable USB tethering on your Android phone to Mac OS X Lion

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb-tethering, macos

I want to tether an unlimited data plan on a Nexus S *(with 2.3.6)* via USB cable to a MacBook Air *(with OS X Lion)*.

1. The articles I read imply that given Apple's restrictions, that's imposible!
2. Found a [question for Froyo](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1959/4168) and one [tethering on a Snow Leopard](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/11590/4168), but they all rely on third party apps.

Is there any hack to make it work out of the box?

Comment: Isn't it OSX that isn't playing nice with the phone, not the other way around?  If you want to hack OSX to work without using any other software, I would guess you're out of luck, but you should probably ask on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: Easy Tether works for me for USB tethering on OS X Lion. http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15735/15, http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5168/15

Comment: @MatthewRead thanks for the Idea, I'll give [Ask Different a shot](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32152/how-to-enable-usb-tethering-on-your-android-phone-to-mac-os-x-lion).

Comment: @garycomtois I've seen bot your answers, but I still thing this is such a basic functionality, that Gingebread 2.3.6 should be able to handle by itself. I'll keep on looking, but thanks for the safety net options.

Comment: @garycomtois, I give up: if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it as the solution to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy Tether works for me for USB tethering on OS X Lion. android.stackexchange.com/q/15735/15, android.stackexchange.com/q/5168/15

To elaborate, here are the steps involved:

1. Open the Easy Tether application on your Android device and select USB (you will see the ET notification in the notification bar).
2. Plug your Android device into your machine via USB.
3. Open Network Preferences, select EasyTether and select Connect.

**Also, if you do any Android dev**, make sure to follow the Mobile Stream's  [FAQ](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android_faq.html) (although I just moved the .kext to the trash since `kextunload` was not working for me):

> **ADB on Mac OS X stops recognizing the attached device after installing > EasyTether driver**
>
> Do not follow this advice if you are not a software developer who uses
>   the Android SDK on Mac. Otherwise run "sudo kextunload
>   /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext" to unload the
>   EasyTether driver manually. Load it again with kextload when/if
>   necessary.